# Unable to cast object of type(Linq To Object)

Tags: linq-to-objects

```
   Function searchByName(lName As String) As List(Of Employees)

        Dim employees As New Employees
        Dim employeeList As New List(Of Employees)
        Dim resultList As New List(Of Employees)
        employeeList = employees.getEmployeeObject

        resultList = From employeesObj In employeeList
                     Where employeesObj.LastName = lName
                     Select employeesObj.EmployeeID
        Return resultList
    End Function
```

Comment: Try wrapping your query in parens and adding ToList... `resultList = (From... Select employeesObj.EmployeeID).ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

The result of most Linq methods, which also applies to the built in comprehension syntax used here, is `IEnumerable(Of T)` and not `List(Of T)`. In order to return the result of your expression then you will need to get the results into a list and the most typical way that is done is by calling the `ToList` extension method on the resulting `IEnumerable(Of Employees)` reference.

Ex:

```
resultList = From employeesObj In employeeList
             Where employeesObj.LastName = lName
             Select employeesObj.EmployeeID
Return resultList.ToList()
```